# Meteor.js Handlebar Returns different Text depending on current Route in Iron Router

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, handlebars.js

When using Iron Router with Meteor.js 0.8.3, how can I have a text in a view template that changes depending on which route the user is on?

For example, if a user is at `/profile`, the text would be `User Profile` and if he is at `/` the text will be `Home`.

**header.html**

```
<template name="header">
    <h1>{{ routeTitle }}</h1>
</template>
```

**profile.html**

```
<template name="profile">
    {{> header}}
</template>
```

**router.js**

```
Router.map( function() {

    this.route('index', {
        path: '/',
        template: 'index'
    })

    this.route('profile', {
        path: '/profile/:_id',
        template: 'profile',
        data: function() { return Users.findOne(this.params._id); }
    })

})
```

Answer (score 1):

I personally store my own properties in the route options like this :

```
Router.map(function(){
  this.route("index", {
    // iron-router standard properties
    path: "/",
    // custom properties
    title: "Home"
    //
    controller: "IndexController"
  });
  this.route("profile", {
    path: "/profile/:_id",
    title: "User profile",
    controller: "ProfileController"
  });
});
```

Then I extend the Router with a set of utilities functions to access the current route.

```
_.extend(Router,{
  currentRoute:function(){
    return this.current()?this.current().route:"";
  }
});

UI.registerHelper("currentRoute",Router.currentRoute.bind(Router));
```

Using these utilities, you can call `Router.currentRoute()` in JS which happens to be a reactive data source too, as it acts as a wrapper for `Router.current()`.

Use `Router.currentRoute() && Router.currentRoute().options.title` to check whether there is a current route and fetch the title you declared in the route definition.

In templates you can use `{{currentRoute.options.title}}` to fetch the current title, this is helpful when working with iron-router layouts.

If you want to get more specific you can even mimic the `Router.path` and `pathFor` helper behavior :

```
_.extend(Router,{
  title:function(routeName){
    return this.routes[routeName] && this.routes[routeName].options.title;
  }
});

UI.registerHelper("titleFor",Router.title.bind(Router));
```

Now you can call `Router.title("index")` in JS and `{{titleFor "index"}}` in templates.

You can even get as far as having a dedicated helper for the current route title, as you suggested in your question :

```
UI.registerHelper("currentRouteTitle",function(){
  return Router.currentRoute() && Router.currentRoute().options.title;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this very easily with `data` param of the path:

```
Router.map(function() {

  this.route('...', {
    ...
    data: function() {
      return {
        importantText: 'User Profile',
      };
    },
  });

});
```

Now use it as any other data object in your rendered template, layout template, or any of the templates rendered to named area:

```
{{importantText}}
```